# Why a GeneratorExit instance is replaced with another one inside an inner coroutine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

I'm developing my own async-library, and have been facing an issue regarding `coroutine.throw()`. Take a look at the code below. This code works as I expect.

```py
import types
import pytest


@types.coroutine
def sleep_forever():
    yield lambda __: None


async def async_fn():
    try:
        await sleep_forever()
    except BaseException as e:
        print(id(e), 'caught')
        if e.args and (e.args[0] == 'Hello'):
            return
    pytest.fail()


async def wrapper():
    return await async_fn()


@pytest.mark.parametrize('exc_cls', (Exception, BaseException, GeneratorExit))
def test_exc(exc_cls):
    print("\n", exc_cls)
    coro = async_fn()
    coro.send(None)
    e = exc_cls('Hello')
    print(id(e), 'about to be thrown')
    try:
        coro.throw(e)
    except StopIteration:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main(['-s', __file__])
```

```
 <class 'Exception'>
139665311893360 about to be thrown
139665311893360 caught
.
 <class 'BaseException'>
139665311894960 about to be thrown
139665311894960 caught
.
 <class 'GeneratorExit'>
139665312313152 about to be thrown
139665312313152 caught
.
```

All the tests succeeded, meaning `async_fn()` successfully received the `'Hello'` in each test case. You can also see the exception instance at the `coro.throw(e)` line and the one at the `except BaseException as e:` line are identical as thier ids are the same.

However things went wrong when I wrapped the `async_fn()` in another async function. (Replacing the `coro = async_fn()` line with `coro = wrapper()`)

```
 <class 'Exception'>
140647138076928 about to be thrown
140647138076928 caught
.
 <class 'BaseException'>
140647138078608 about to be thrown
140647138078608 caught
.
 <class 'GeneratorExit'>
140647138525488 about to be thrown
140647138078288 caught
F

==================== FAILURES =====================
_______ test_exc[GeneratorExit] _______

exc_cls = <class 'GeneratorExit'>

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('exc_cls', (Exception, BaseException, GeneratorExit))
    def test_exc(exc_cls):
        print("\n", exc_cls)
        coro = wrapper()
        coro.send(None)
        e = exc_cls('Hello')
        print(id(e), 'about to be thrown')
        try:
>           coro.throw(e)

test_exc.py:32: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
test_exc.py:21: in wrapper
    return await async_fn()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

    async def async_fn():
        try:
            await sleep_forever()
        except BaseException as e:
            print(id(e), 'caught')
            if e.args and (e.args[0] == 'Hello'):
                return
>       pytest.fail()
E       Failed

test_exc.py:17: Failed
```

As you can see, the test failed and the exception instances weren't identical when `exc_cls` is `GeneratorExit`.

I feel like I should not directly instantiate a `GeneratorExit`. It might always have to be instantiated through `coroutine.close()`. In other words, there is no way to pass a `GeneratorExit` instance a value, and thus, there is no way to make the tests succeed.

I'm not 100% sure it is impossible. Is there a way to make it work? (I don't need the exception instances to be identical. I just want to pass the `'Hello'` to `async_fn()`.)

#### Environment

- CPython 3.9.7
- pytest 7.3.1